# render from one view to another view in jsf

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, richfaces, ajax4jsf

I have this:

A parent view that includes

- firstView
- secondView

The firstView has a

```
<rich:panel id="toRender">
```

and the second has a

```
<a4j:ajax render="toRender">
```

How can I render from the secondView the panel from the firstView?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Find out its real client ID, prefix it with `:` to make it an absolute client ID and then use it instead.

For starters, who haven't memorized how client IDs are generated and what all JSF [`NamingContainer`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/component/NamingContainer.html) are, the easiest way to find out the real client ID is to open the page in browser and do a *View Source* and locate the HTML element which is generated by the JSF component of interest and grab the value of its `id` attribute.

It may look like this

```html
<someHtmlElement id="someId:otherId:lastId">
```

In that case, you need to use

```html
<a4j:ajax render=":someId:otherId:lastId">
```

If one of the parent JSF `NamingContainer` components (like `<h:form>`) doesn't have a fixed `id` assigned yet and thus you end up with an autogenerated `j_idt123` or something in the client ID, then you need to give the JSF `NamingContainer` component a fixed ID.